# Node.js - mysql query timeout

Tags: mysql, node.js

How do I set a timeout for a mysql query in node.js?

```
/*...*/ 

var mysql = require("mysql");

/* ...*/ 

app.get("/", function(req, res) { 
     connection.query("SELECT ...", function(err, rows, fields) {
 /* I want this query to fail if the ^_ callback is not invoked within x seconds */

     });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look up this link:

http://www.exratione.com/2013/01/nodejs-connections-will-end-close-and-otherwise-blow-up/

But the module doesn't seems to have any support for it at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what would be an alternative? Without the timeout functionality, it seems that the module is not suitable for production.. hmm.